# How can I name the output of a compiled source file in a certain way?

Tags: terminal, compiling, command, c++, compiler

In terminal, I have compiled a source file named "file.C". I did this by typing g++ file.C -o file.

Now, I'd like to know how can I use Unix commands to name the output as "helloworld.out"?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that

```
$ g++ file.C -o file
```

will create an executable called `file`, one would hopefully have been able to extrapolate that

```
$ g++ file.C -o helloworld.out
```

will create an executable falled `helloworld.out`.